# Angular 7 switchMap calling Twice

Tags: angular, typescript, switchmap

I have been trying to get this to work with just one request.

But when the function calls the service it fires the get request twice.

If I remove the switchMap it fires once.

The http request is fired twice it should only fire once.

Any help is appreciated!

```
loadReports(val: {}) {

  const modelCode = val['modelCode'];

  this._reportService.getReportTypes(modelCode).pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(() => this._reportService.getReportTypes(modelCode)),
    share(),
  ).subscribe(
    (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    },
    (error) => {
   ...
    },
    () => {
    ...
    }
  );

}
```

here is the service

```
getReportTypes(modelCode: string): Observable<any> { 
...
    return this._http.get(apiUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap( _ => console.log('fetched product types')),
      map((resp: Response) => {
      // return data;
          return resp.body['data'].map((item: any[]) => this._adapter.adapt(item));
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>('getReportTypes Error', []))
    );
}
```

Thanks
For your help

Comment: `I am using switchMap because the user selects from a drop down.` that makes no sense to me. What you trying to do here, and what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: This is just the reason why I am using the switchmap...  if the data is still loading and the user selects another item it should cancel what is coming in for the new call. I will remove that comment. It is executing the function twice on every call

Comment: why did you use switchMap and calling same api again

Comment: I think you need to change the title to `Why I am calling a service twice` ;)

Comment: @RezaRahmati The function is called when the user selects a value from a drop down. if the user selects before the request is returned then it is possible that the server returns the second request first  and the first request second. Thereby you would see the values for the first request for the second user selected value. ie. rq2 -> rs1 ...

Comment: You *cancel* a previous HTTP request in Angular by *unsubscribing*. You've added the `share()` operator which disables cancelling.

Comment: @cgTag switchMap cancels the previous subscription and subscribes to the new one. Share is an added artifact that I added in trying to figure this problem out. I have removed share but am still seeing two duplicate calls.

Comment: When is `loadReports()` called?

Comment: @cgTag there is an output that emits a call to the parent setSelected(val: any) { ...
     this.loadReports(val);
  }  ---- this is called on (selectionChange) of the dropdown